# Set screen location of external application child window?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, api

Hi I have a program that I monitor an external application. I am able to set the screen location of the application but I want all child windows of that application to open in the same location.

Her is my code I am usion to set the location of the Parent window.

```
Public Function OpenApplication()
        Dim ApplicationProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\test.exe")
        ApplicationProcess.WaitForInputIdle()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Dim ApplicationHandle = ApplicationProcess.MainWindowHandle
        SetWindowPos(ApplicationHandle, 0, 0, 0, 803, 460, 0)
        ApplicationProcess.WaitForInputIdle()
        Return (False)
    End Function
```

Comment: So why not, just have any child windows that get created in test.exe position themselves to be in the same place as the main (parent) window. Did you create test.exe? Can you edit it? If not, then you will not be able to control the placement of the child windows from that application, since that application will be controlling its own children or they will be positioned by default if the parent does not specifically place them.

Comment: I did not create the test.exe but I think it is possible to get control of them I just dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site. I believe you can accomplish what you want from here. It is all about Obtaining External Window Handles and Window Captions, but it is too much to copy here.

[Here is the link](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/obtaining-external-window-handles-and-window-captions-with-visual-studio-2012.htm)